# what may cause white page in yii when launch app

Tags: yii

i am a new yii developer. I got ready working project from my friend(yii1). But, when i run it in my localhost nothing is happening except white page. I do not know why. Please, give me hint to about the causes of this case.

Comment: Check your application and server logs for possible hints.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have error reporting enabled? See [White screen of death](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26477342/873453) for more information.

If your friend can run it without problem, it might be because database connection is not set properly. See in `/protected/config/main.php`, under `components`. There should be either connection to database or link to the file, where the connection to database is set.